# Any advantages / disadvantages between create-project symfony/website-skeleton to create-project symfony/skeleton

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I just started using symfony last night. Im still learning till now by following the tutorials in youtube, and read some documentation in the site.

I noticed that there's two ways to create a new project create-project symfony/website-skeleton and create-project symfony/skeleton. When I creating a new project Im using create-project symfony/skeleton.

Tried to do some research, and I found this(https://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-the-symfony-standard-edition). Except for this reason

Question:Is there any advantages / disadvantages between create-project symfony/website-skeleton to create-project symfony/skeleton? Which should I use as a beginner?

Comment: Use the website-skeleton to get started.  It automatically brings in and configures most of the functionality a typical website needs.  Once you start understanding how things fit together you might shift to the original skeleton which gives you just enough functionality to get going.  And then you add in any specific bundles you might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before, the Symfony standard edition was the recommended way to create new Symfony projects. It brings bundles like Swiftmailer, Doctrine or either Monolog.

But you might not want to use all of them, so before you had to remove the dependencies that you don't want.

Symfony now uses the inverse approach. This is called Symfony Flex.

With flex, you only add what you really need.

The `symfony/website-skeleton` is just the standard edition we used to know... but with flex.

So you should use `symfony/skeleton` if you want to learn symfony concepts.

And you should use `symfony/website-skeleton` if you want to start creating web applications using popular bundles.

Comment: I have a question. Have you tried laravel framework? Why laravel has more than developer than symfony?

Comment: I didn't so I can't tell you why.